# Two seemingly identical LINQ queries. One works, the other doesn't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

The query below works:

```
var result = (from p in db.Permissions
              join z in db.PermissionOverridesByUsers on p.id equals z.PermissionID into x
              from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where userRoleIds.Contains((Guid)(p.ParentRoleID))
              select new RolePermissionViewModel
                         {
                             id = p.id,
                             Name = p.Name,
                             IsSet = ((y.id != null && y.id > 0) ? false : true)
                         }).ToList(); // If an exception exists, IsSet = false, otherwise = true.
```

This one produces a null reference error on *IsSet*

```
var query1 = (from p in db.Permissions
              where userRoleIds.Contains((Guid)(p.ParentRoleID))
              select p).ToList();

var query2 = (from ov in db.PermissionOverridesByUsers
              where ov.AffectedUserID == id
              select ov).ToList();

var result = (from q1 in query1
              join z in query2 on q1.id equals z.PermissionID into x
              from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new RolePermissionViewModel
                         {
                             id = q1.id,
                             Name = q1.Name,
                             IsSet = ((y.id != null && y.id > 0) ? false : true)
                         }).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make this second *result* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is interpreted by a query provider to generate the appropriate query to return the requested results.  To the query provider, the construct `join ... into x from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty()` is a sign to generate a left outer join.  As the entities are materialized, the provider recognizes `NULL` values and what the corresponding default value is for a given type.  Those defaults are what are used when evaluating expressions involving them.

Your second query however is pulled into LINQ to Objects when you pulled all the results into lists.  Now querying these lists are subject to regular C# rules.  Now the `x.DefaultIfEmpty()` part will now yield a collection of one item that is the default value of the collection type.  In the case of a reference type, that means `null`.  You need to provide an alternate (non-null) value to use instead.  The default instance is usually enough.

```
var result =
    (from q1 in query1
    join z in query2 on q1.id equals z.PermissionID into x
    from y in x.DefaultIfEmpty(new PermissionOverridesByUsers())
    select new RolePermissionViewModel
    {
        id = q1.id,
        Name = q1.Name,
        IsSet = ((y.id != null && y.id > 0) ? false : true)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you very much!